# OutOfMemory Exception on remote execution using Powershell Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, invoke-command, remote-execution

I am trying to execute an exe on a remote computer using invoke-command. Executing the exe on the remote machine after logging into the machine using remote desktop takes 1GB of memory and executes to completion after a minute. Whereas when I execute the same exe using Invoke-Command on the same machine, the process returns an OutOfMemoryException and ends suddenly. My invoke command is as simple as `Invoke-Command -Session $someSessionVariable -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression "abc.exe --arg arg"} -AsJob`.

Am I missing something regarding the restrictions on remote invocation?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://blog.patricknielsen.net/2012/01/powershell-remote-system-call-using.html

Comment: Why do you even use `iex` for calling a native program? PowerShell is a *shell*. Executing commands is what it does.

Comment: @Joey - while that is true, powershell has so MANY problems with passing the arguments to an external program that it is at times easier to just use `iex`

Comment: But `iex` ist just a layer above all that problems, at least how I understand it. You just add a layer of indirection while solving no problem at all.

Comment: Thanks David, the suggestion helped.

Comment: any final solution about it ?

Comment: @DavidBrabant that was the solution for me! Thanks very much!!!

Answer (score 11):

Complete PowerShell script, based on **mjolinor**'s answer, for anyone who wants to skip the reasons and just make it work:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 1000000
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\Quotas\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 1000000
Restart-Service WinRM
```

Answer (score 7):

From:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384372(v=vs.85).aspx

The defult memory limit on remote shells is 150MB

MaxMemoryPerShellMB
 Specifies the maximum amount of memory allocated per shell, including the shell's child processes. The default is 150 MB.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The page has many more default parameters that one using winrm has to checkout.

Comment: Using remote/background jobs means you're going to be dealing with constrained runspaces and deserialized objects being returned. What works in a local/unconstrained runspace may need to be re-factored to work in that enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to mjolinor's answer, you can change the MaxMemoryPerShellMB by running:

```
sl WSMan:\localhost\Shell
Set-Item MaxMemoryPerShellMB 300
```

Ref: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/30/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory.aspx