# R Execution failed with the application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way

Tags: r, powershell, dynamic-memory-allocation, windows-server-2012-r2

I am new to R, kindly help me with below error.

Calling R code using batch file (e.g: c:\batchfile\x.bat) in a machine which has dynamic memory i.e. based on load memory and cores will increase. 
in above approach everything I executing with out error. R code using RODBCext
koRpus, akmeans, lsa, stringr, topicmodels, RWeka, lda, snowfall, tm, openNLP, reshape2, plyr, RODBC packages.

But while calling x.bat file using remote server within powershell (e.g.,Invoke-Command -Computername 'Servername' {Start-Process  'C:\batchfile\x.bat' -wait}) resulting below errors:

1. LoadLibrary failure:  The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.
2. just-in-time debugging errors
3. This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your batch file, did u start the correct version of R with all the library installed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665981/outofmemory-exception-on-remote-execution-using-powershell-invoke-command might be relevant