# I am unable to resolve "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' this error

Tags: powershell, zip, powershell-remoting

I am writing a powershell script to create a zip folder on the remote machine of size 47 gb in the C:\ drive . The folder is also in C:\ drive . The C:\ drive  have 66gb free space but still gives me error of "not enough memory resources" to create the zip so I tried to create the zip from C:\ to H:. My H:\ drive have 121 gb free but still is giving me error.
I am attaching the screenshot of both errors.

[image]

```
$curentDirectory = $PSScriptRoot
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }
            Write-Output "Script Current Directory is:"$curentDirectory
            Write-Output "Reading Configuration From :"$curentDirectory"/config.xml"

            $myData = [xml](Get-Content $curentDirectory"/config.xml" -ErrorAction Stop)
            $machineName = $myData.'tangoEnvironment'.VM01.machineName
            $machineDrive= $myData.'tangoEnvironment'.VM01.machineDrive
            $remoteUser = $myData.'tangoEnvironment'.VM01.remoteUser
            $remotePassword = $myData.'tangoEnvironment'.VM01.remotePassword
            $userCred     =     New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential($remoteUser, (convertto- 
                    securestring $remotePassword -asplaintext -force))
                    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $machineName -Credential $userCred -ScriptBlock {
                        
                        Write-Host    ""   
                        Write-Host     "Response from Jump Server($env:COMPUTERNAME) ..."
                        # Rest of service
                        Compress-Archive -Path C:/Humera -DestinationPath H:"/Humera.zip" 
                        
                    }

   cmd /c pause
```

Comment: ZIP has limitations regarding the size of archive and files inside archive. Try to use 7-zip instead.

Comment: Disk space is not the issue here. `Invoke-Command` means the code is running in a remote shell, and there will be a limit to how much memory (RAM, not disk space) that the shell can allocate.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In addition to both valid points above, ZIP works in a work area, and writes its output based on that work area.  In some cases it will need at least 100% extra space in order to achieve its goal.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell remote sessions have a small memory limit - see [the answers to this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665981/outofmemory-exception-on-remote-execution-using-powershell-invoke-command)

> From:
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384372(v=vs.85).aspx -
> The defult memory limit on remote shells is 150MB

To resolve, this can be increased:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 1000000
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\Quotas\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 1000000
Restart-Service WinRM
```

But [Compress-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.1) also has a size limit!

> The Compress-Archive cmdlet uses the Microsoft .NET API
> `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive` to compress files. The maximum file
> size is 2 GB because there's a limitation of the underlying API.

You will need to use a third-party utility like 7zip to compress a single file that large.